# I have a scheduled Java Spring application . Can any one tell me the format of fixedDelay?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

In the Java Spring application, If any job is scheduled like...
`@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000 * 30, fixedDelay = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 5)`

Please help me in understanding what this **(fixedDelay = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 5)** does..??

Comment: Please read the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelay--

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelay--), `fixedDelay` defines a period in milliseconds between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next.

In your case, it basically sets it to every 5 days:

- 3600: this is the number of seconds in an hour;
- 1000: this turns the seconds into milliseconds;
- 24: number of hours in a day;
- 5: number of days.

You could also set it as `432000000` (which is the result of `1000 * 3600 * 24 * 5`) but it is way harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

**initialDelay** - If you want to add *delay to the first execution* of the method for some reason, you can use initialDelay parameter indicating the number of milliseconds to wait before the first execution of the method.

**fixedDelay** - adds a *delay between two executions of task/method*.

[Fixed Delay Fixed Rate](https://javahowtos.com/guides/107-spring/321-difference-between-fixedrate-and-fixeddelay-parameter-in-scheduled-in-spring.html#:%7E:text=The%20number%20you%20define%20for%20fixedDelay%20represents%20time%20in%20milliseconds.&text=If%20you%20want%20to%20add,first%20execution%20of%20the%20method)